# Auth token handling for Gatling

Tags: scala, authentication, gatling

Doing performance testing of API using Gatling.

Scenario:
Login (authToken will be generated in header)
For GET, POST, PUT request, need to pass that generated authToken in header

Here's my code snippet:

```
package apitest

import scala.concurrent.duration.*
import io.gatling.core.Predef.*
import io.gatling.http.Predef.*
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef.*
import scala.language.postfixOps

class TestEnv4trial extends Simulation {

    var e1: String = "https://testenv1-dev.net"
    var e2: String = "https://testenv2-dev.net"

    var BaseUrl: String = e1

    var pwd: String = "pass123"

    // Users
    var admin: String = "admin123"

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
        .inferHtmlResources()

    val login_headers = Map(
        "Accept" -> """*/*""",
        "Connection" -> "keep-alive",
        "Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
    )

    val scn1 = scenario("Admin Login")
        .exec(http("Login Admin")
            .post({BaseUrl} + "/api/user/login")
            .formParam("username", admin123)
            .formParam("password", pass123)
            .check(jsonPath("$.authToken").saveAs("tokenId")))
        .exec { session => println(session("tokenId").as[String]); session } //authToken getting printed

    val common_headers = Map(
        "Accept" -> """*/*""",
        "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language" -> "en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8",
        "Authorization" -> "Bearer " + $tokenId, //With hardcoded authToken works. Need to pass generated authToken in prev scenario here.
        "Connection" -> "keep-alive",
    )

    val scn2 = scenario("All Employees")
            .exec(http("All Employees")
            .post("/api/employee/lists/")
            .headers(common_headers)
            .body(RawFileBody("test/TestEnv4trial/employees_request.json")).asJson)

    setUp(
        scn1.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocol),
        scn2.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocol))
}
```

When I hardcode authToken generated in scn1 in common_headers, scn2 works.
But when I use tokenId, its not able to identify tokenId.

How do I pass saved key tokenId in common_headers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
"Authorization" -> "Bearer " + $tokenId
```

This doesn't compile.

Currently, you're using Session attributes, meaning `tokenId` is scoped for the single user executing `scn1`.
There's no way for a user executing `scn2` to be able to reach it as is.

Comment: What could be solution then? Tried everything but not able to crack this mystery :(
How to share token across different scenarios?